# Make thunar mount drives into /media rather than /run/media/username?

Tags: arch-linux, thunar, udisks

It's pretty annoying that thunar mounts a drive to `/run/media/user_name/XX` instead of `/media/XX`, can I change that behavior ? I'm running latest arch linux

Comment: [Here's an extensive thread on this `udisk`/`udisk2` issue,](https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2012-April/025994.html) including hints on why `/media` is supposed to go away.

Comment: @sr_ yeah, doesn't matter for me.. it's a laptop that only I can use, reading that page now

Answer (score 2):

If you're desperate, you can search and replace the path in the thunar sources, then recompile thunar.

Alternatively, you could make /media into a soft link to /run/media/user_name, or the other way around, since you're the only one using the laptop.